# Hololens application stopping at splash screen

Tags: camera, hololens

I'm working on a Unity project for Hololens, that uses the camera to capture pictures, send them to a photo recognition API and displays the result. The project works perfectly fine in unity, but not on the emulator/Hololens.

Unfortunately, I wrote a lot of code at once, so i don't know at what point this problem started. The problem show's up after building the project and running it on the Hololens/emulator in Debug mode. On the Hololens, I see the starting window (the one you see after you open any application). After i place it, i see `End showing splash screen.` on the Output window in Visual Studio, and it just doesn't go any further (but doesn't freeze either, just does nothing).

I don't know where it's coming from, since no exceptions are thrown, but i suspect the camera is the cause. Earlier, i had to comment this line of code:

```
transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3((CameraManager.Resolution.width * .5f), (CameraManager.Resolution.height * .5f), 10));
```

because the function `ScreenToWorldPoint` was throwing the following exception:

```
Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 0.000000, 0.000000, 10.000000) (Camera rect 0 0 0 0)
```

As you see it says that the Camera rect's size is 0. I even tried directly logging the camera's dimensions to make sure (`Debug.Log(Camera.main.pixelWidth + ", " + Camera.main.pixelHeight)`), and sure enough, they were (0, 0) on the Hololens/emulator.

I made sure that webcam is supported, and that my camera settings are all set, but that didn't help either.

So i'm not sure if that's the cause of the problem or simply a symptom. And I can't start anywhere since neither the Output nor the Error window show anything wrong. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for reading!

Edit: [Here's](http://txt.do/d62dx) the entire output log from beginning to end.

Edit2: I don't know if this is significant, but if I paused execution (in Visual Studio), it always seem to be at Build/ProjectName/App.css => Line 78:

```
[MTAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var app = new App();
   CoreApplication.Run(app); //<===== Here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i didn't enable "Virtual Reality Supported" under Other settings in PlayerSettings. It's really dumb, but i hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check any of your Start() methods. You might have some code that is CPU intensive. Even if it runs smoothly in Unity, doesn't mean it will run easily on HoloLens since their CPU is not powerful.

Also, to avoid any Camera problems, make sur to use the Camera prefab from this
repository :
**https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity**

Those are just some thoughts, hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately though it didn't work; Most Start() methods are perfectly normal, and i already am using the camera prefab.

Comment: Oh I'm glad you found the problem!